# How do I make my DIV only take up the width of the elements it contains?

Tags: html, css, width

I have a little form that is inside a larger div:

```
<div id="confirmEmailContainer">
  <form class="edit_user" id="edit_user_2" action="/users/2" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="hWjOQEpKyMKVrk9+vWEeenl3D49rVe4hXFKgF4lza09xXRo0HENKMqGRpq9xUflWqbGJUdoxrmQrsksQWV5s7g==" />

    <div class="field">
      <label for="user_email">Email</label> <span class="required">*</span> <br>
      <div>
        <input size="30" style="display: inline;" type="text" value="myemail@msn.com" name="user[email]" id="user_email" /> 
        <span id="emailConfirmedStatus">
          <div class="unconfirmed" style="display: block"><img style="vertical-align:middle" src="/assets/x-mark-621493006f6052df98aa84352a33f21bccabfc670129ca9572009545745040d9.png" alt="X mark" width="16" height="16" /> Unconfirmed</div>
          <div class="confirmed" style="display: none"><img style="vertical-align:middle" src="/assets/checkmark-b87ae8ffea696b9c9587f26fdb656af7a21da4f7f73da01fc4bef9b35a1b9465.svg" alt="Checkmark" width="16" height="16" /> Confirmed</div>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="actions buttonContainer">
      <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Send Confirmation Email" id="submit" class="button btn" data-disable-with="Send Confirmation Email" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I do not specify CSS `width` properties anywhere, including the form or its container:

```css
#confirmEmailContainer {
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
}

form {
    margin: 4% 15%;
    font-family: Manuelle;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

but yet the container is almost taking up the entire width of the content area -- https://jsfiddle.net/70pgd6jn/ .  How do I make the form only occupy the width of its elements ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for the `display: inline-block` property, which will permit your container element to only occupy the space it requires.

```css
#confirmEmailContainer {
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  Look at the updated Fiddle with your suggestion -- https://jsfiddle.net/70pgd6jn/1/ .

Comment: Oh wait, you mean tto say "display:inline-block;".  That works.

Answer (score 0):

you should add `float: left` to `#confirmEmailContainer` and `overflow: hidden` to `#content`